# Нужно узнать размер папки

Tags: c#

последовательность такая, проверяем размер каталога, запоминаем, через некоторое время снова проверяем, сравниваем и по результату что то делаем.

но, если использовать этот способ, то размер каталога определяется верно только первый раз, второй раз выдает тот же размер, если зайти в папку руками, нажать обновить средствами винды, размеры файлов в папке отображает уже пересчитанными, то после таких манипуляций и функция корректно определяет размер.
пробовал по другому считать размер, получаю  unauthorized access
я не программиста админ, не оч умный, помогите )

```
    public static long DirSize(DirectoryInfo d)
    {
        {                
            FileInfo[] fis;
            try
            {
                fis = d.GetFiles();
            }
            catch
            {
                return 0;
            }

            long fileSize = (from file in fis select (long)file.Length).Sum();
            long subdirSize = (from dir in d.GetDirectories() select DirSize(dir)).Sum();

            return fileSize + subdirSize;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Гляньте в сторону FileSystemWatcher

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант действительно использовать FileSystemWatcher: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ruru/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.changed(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: можно попробовать но думаю filesystemwatcher уместнее использовать, когда ждешь изменений в файловой системе, мне же, наоборот нужно узнать, когда изменения прекращаются, запись в каталоги останавливается, думаю будет избыточно постоянно мониторить, достаточно раз в час в полчаса сравнить размеры